# Exponentiated quotient that is also under a floor/ceiling function

Tags: notation, exponentiation, ceiling-and-floor-functions

$$\biggr \lfloor \frac ab \biggr \rfloor^e $$

Or

$$\biggr (\biggr \lfloor \frac ab \biggr \rfloor \biggr )^e$$

I feel like the second option looks worse, but the first option assumes that a floor/ceiling function can "multitask" as  a paranthetical enclosement. So, is the first one acceptable?

Comment: In my opinion, the first expression is clear and there is no risk of confusion.

Comment: The point of notation is to clearly communicate an idea.  It is not a question of whether or not the notation can "multitask"---it is a question is what gets the job done.  Do you believe that $$\left\lfloor \frac{a}{b} \right\rfloor$$ is ambiguous?  If so, add some extra parentheses.  Otherwise, don't.  I don't think that there is an objectively correct answer to this question---it is a matter of opinion (and, more specifically, taste).

Answer (score 3):

The first option is perfectly clear. Any function that encloses an expression would not need another pair of parentheses to enclose itself

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).